# Points on a rotated rectangle

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, algorithm, geometry

I'm attempting to calculate the bottom-left point in a rectangle as it is rotated around. I've attempted to Google it, but apparently I'm missing something. I'm attempting to use a transformation matrix to calculate the point.

For my setup, I have a rectangle clip called "test" and a clip called "pnt" that I'm trying to keep on the lower left point. Here is the code for my demo. I've just thrown this onto the first frame of the timeline to test:

```
//declare initial position of points
pnt.x = (test.x - test.width/2);
pnt.y = (test.y + test.height/2);

//distance between corner and center
var dx:Number = pnt.x - test.x;
var dy:Number = pnt.y - test.y;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,rotate);


//x' = xc + dx cos(theta) - dy sin(theta)
//y' = yc + dx sin(theta) + dy cos(theta)
function rotate(e:Event):void{
    test.rotation++;

    // use the transformation matrix to calculate the new x and y of the corner
    pnt.x = test.x + dx*Math.cos(test.rotation*(Math.PI/180)) - dy*Math.sin(test.rotation*(Math.PI/180));
    pnt.y = test.y + dx*Math.sin(test.rotation*(Math.PI/180)) + dy*Math.cos(test.rotation*(Math.PI/180));

    trace("X: " + Math.cos(rotation));
    trace("Y: " + pnt.y);
    // calculate the new distance to the center
    dx = pnt.x - test.x;
    dy = pnt.y - test.y;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding "pnt" as a child of "test" and rotating them as one object?

Comment: This is a demo to attempt to solve the problem. The actual problem exists within a physics engine where I can't rely on embedded movie clips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can model the trajectory of a single point by

```
(x',y') = (xc + r cos(theta + theta0), yc + r sin(theta + theta0))
```

where

```
(x', y') = new position
(xc, yc) = center point things rotate around
(x, y) = initial point
r = distance between (x,y) and (xc, yc)
theta = counterclockwise rotation, in radians
theta0 = initial rotation of (x,y), in radians
```

Our initial point tells us that

```
r sin(theta0) = (y - yc) 
r cos(theta0) = (x - xc)
```

By the power of trigonomerty:

```
r cos(theta + theta0) =
r cos(theta)cos(theta0) - r sin(theta)sin(theta0) = 
cos(theta)(x - xc) - sin(theta)(y - yc)
```

and

```
r sin(theta + theta0) = 
r sin(theta)cos(theta0) + r cos(theta)sint(theta0)
sin(theta)(x - xc) + cos(theta)(y - yc)
```

**Therefore**, given

1. The center point `(xc, yc)` that stuff is rotating around
2. The point to track `(x, y)` - (your rectangle corner)
3. A rotation `theta`, in radians

**The new position of the point will be:**

```
x' = xc + dx cos(theta) - dy sin(theta)
y' = yc + dx sin(theta) + dy cos(theta)
```

with `dx` and `dy` given by

```
dx = x - xc
dy = y - yc
```

Comment: I've edited my code to attempt to do this, but it still isn't working. The point doesn't move at all now. Did I implement it wrong in some way? I changed the code in my original post to the code I have now.

Comment: You aren't supposed to reset the `dx` - it depends only on the initial position.

Comment: FYI: "theta" used above is not in degrees, but in radians. To calculate radians from degrees: `radians = (degrees * Pi / 180)`. Other than that, this answer works perfectly (and I had to look at a lot of answers to find this working one)! Also... I would like to flip this around a bit and solve for `x` and `y` rather than `x'` and `y'` (I know my destinations, but I need to know where to start from). Can anyone offer a little help? Thanks!

Comment: Re: Solving for `x`/`y` rather than `x'`/`y'`... `theta = (theta * -1)` Durrr.... =)

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who found this as I did via the Google...

Here is the above answer in JavaScript/jQuery form, where `$element` is the `$('#element')` jQuery object, `iDegrees` is the angle you wish to rotate, `iX`/`iY` are the coordinates to the point you wish to know the destination of, and `iCenterXPercent`/`iCenterYPercent` represent the percentage into the element (as per CSS's `transform-origin`) where the rotation will occur:

```
function XYRotatesTo($element, iDegrees, iX, iY, iCenterXPercent, iCenterYPercent) {
    var oPos = $element.position(),
        iCenterX = ($element.outerWidth() * iCenterXPercent / 100),
        iCenterY = ($element.outerHeight() * iCenterYPercent / 100),
        iRadians = (iDegrees * Math.PI / 180),
        iDX = (oPos.left - iCenterX),
        iDY = (oPos.top - iCenterY)
    ;

    return {
        x: iCenterX + (iDX * Math.cos(iRadians)) - (iDY * Math.sin(iRadians)),
        y: iCenterY + (iDX * Math.sin(iRadians)) + (iDY * Math.cos(iRadians))
    };
};
```

eg:

Where does the top-left corner of `<div id='element'>...</div>` end up when rotated by 45 degrees around it's bottom-left corner?

```
var oXY = XYRotatesTo($('#element'), 45, 0, 0, 0, 100);
```