# Points on a (un)rotated rectangle

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, bounding-box

I found [this excellent question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867474/points-on-a-rotated-rectangle) which starts with `x`/`y` (plus the `center x/y` and `degrees/radians`) and calculates the rotated-to `x'`/`y'`. This calculation works perfectly, but I would like to run it in the opposite direction; starting with `x'`/`y'` and `degrees/radians`, I would like to calculate the originating `x`/`y` and the `center x/y`.

```
(x', y') = new position
(xc, yc) = center point things rotate around
(x, y) = initial point
theta = counterclockwise rotation in radians (radians = degrees * Pi / 180)
dx = x - xc
dy = y - yc

x' = xc + dx cos(theta) - dy sin(theta)
y' = yc + dx sin(theta) + dy cos(theta)
```

Or, in JavaScript/jQuery:

```
XYRotatesTo = function($element, iDegrees, iX, iY, iCenterXPercent, iCenterYPercent) {
    var oPos = $element.position(),
        iCenterX = ($element.outerWidth() * iCenterXPercent / 100),
        iCenterY = ($element.outerHeight() * iCenterYPercent / 100),
        iRadians = (iDegrees * Math.PI / 180),
        iDX = (oPos.left - iCenterX),
        iDY = (oPos.top - iCenterY)
    ;

    return {
        x: iCenterX + (iDX * Math.cos(iRadians)) - (iDY * Math.sin(iRadians)),
        y: iCenterY + (iDX * Math.sin(iRadians)) + (iDY * Math.cos(iRadians))
    };
};
```

The math/code above solves for the situation in Figure A; it calculates the position of the destination `x'`/`y'` (green circle) based on the known values for `x`/`y` (red circle), the `center x/y` (blue star) and the `degrees/radians`.

But I need math/code to solve for Figure B; where I can find not only the destination `x`/`y` (green circle), but also the destination `center x/y` (green star) from the known values of the starting `x`/`y` (grey circle, though probably not needed), the destination `x'`/`y'` (red circle) and the `degrees/radians`.

[image: Diagram A and B]

The code above will solve for the destination `x`/`y` (green circle) via `iDegrees * -1` (thanks to @andrew cooke's answer which has since been removed by him), but in order to do that I need to feed into it the location of the destination `center x/y` (green star), and that is the calculations I'm currently missing, as you can see in Diagram C, below:

[image: Diagram C]

So... how do I find the coordinates `?`/`?` (green star) given `n`, `A` (angle) and `x'`/`y'` (red circle)?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find an inverse transformation. You start with the composition of two linear transformations, a translation T and a rotation R. You apply R first to a vector x and T second, so the expression is y = TRx. To solve the inverse problem you need the inverse of TR, written (TR)<sup>-1</sup>, which is equal to R<sup>-1</sup>T<sup>-1</sup>. The inverse of the rotation R is just the rotation by the negative of the angle (which you mention). The inverse of the translation is, similarly, the original translation multiplied by -1. So your answer is x = R<sup>-1</sup>T<sup>-1</sup>y.

In your present situation, you're given the rotation by means of its angle, but you'll need to compute the translation. You'll need the grey circle, which you didn't think you would need. Apply the rotation R (not its inverse) to the gray circle. Subtract this point from the red circle. This is the original translation T. Reverse the sign to get T<sup>-1</sup>.